# Bindskin Option in blender 2.9

Tags: rigging

I've recently updated to Blender 2.9. Now I have two objects, one hair model and one female body model. I want to bind the hair to the model head.

In Maya there's an option bindskin for that, but I'm unable to find it in Blender. Is there an alternative to bindskin in Blender except <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>J</kbd>?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot or a bit more information? Is this particle hair or mesh/hair chards? Is it the whole head that you want to join to the body or is there a hair cap? And is the model rigged (armature)? I'm not that familiar with Maya but "bindskin" sounds like binding the mesh to an armature....?

Comment: Looks like my guess was right [Maya Character Animation](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/maya/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2020/ENU/Maya-CharacterAnimation/files/GUID-CF2C698A-44BB-4CA0-BCB9-DB36500DA812-htm.html)... Oh, and you tagged the Q with *rigging*. In Blender you need to use the "Parent To" operation. Select the mesh first, then the armature (=active object=highlighted in brighter color in the default theme), and press CTRL+P. Then select *With Empty Group* if you want to fix/transfer the weights or *With Automatic Weights* if Blender should calculate them.